# No such table error. SQLite + Xamarin.android

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.android

I am new to xamarin android. I have created SQLite database externally using DB Browser for SQLite and added it to my existing android project. But **I am getting exception as 'no such table: Employee'**

I Followed below step.

- Created new project in Visual Studio 2015 (Android > Blank App(Android)).
- Created database using DB Browser for SQLite. Below is schema

[image: Database Schema]

- Save the file as'EmployeeDB.db3' in Assets folder.
- Set Build Action for this file as 'AndroidAsset'
- In MainActivity.cs I have written below code

  ```
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
  {
      base.OnCreate(bundle);

      // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
      SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

      employeeListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);

      try
      {
          var sqliteFilename = "EmployeeDB.db3";
          string libraryPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
          var path = Path.Combine(libraryPath, sqliteFilename);

          CopyDatabaseIfNotExists(path);
          conn = new SQLiteConnection(path);
          var empList = GetItems();
          empAdapter = new EmployeeAdapter(this, empList.ToList());

          employeeListView.Adapter = empAdapter;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {

          throw;
      }
  }

  private void CopyDatabaseIfNotExists(string path)
  {
      if (!File.Exists(path))
      {
          using (var br = new BinaryReader(Application.Context.Assets.Open("EmployeeDB.db3")))
          {
              using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)))
              {
                  byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                  int length = 0;
                  while ((length = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                  {
                      bw.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }

  public IEnumerable<Employee> GetItems()
  {
      lock (locker)
      {
          return (from i in conn.Table<Employee>() select i).ToList();
      }
  }
  ```

While running, I am getting below exception message.

> "no such table: Employee"

Am I missing somthing? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you can remove `if (!File.Exists(path))` and run it once to force a fresh copy to be written - just to ensure that previous attempts haven't saved an empty database at the target path

Comment: Wow. That worked!. Thanks. But I wonder why it is not taking the fresh copy when I manually add latest file in Asset folder.

Comment: Because the file at the _target_ path was written during one of your first attempts, and it only copies when there's no file at that location. If you want it to "copy when newer" you're going to have to compare the file modification date and time.